# Помогите с программой C++

Tags: c++

Итак, я только начинаю нелегкий путь в C++, так что решил сделать несложную программу: выдача вопросов и счет баллов за них. В суть углубляться не буду, но идея работы программы такая: в подключаемом файле я создаю и инициализирую двумерный вектор, каждый элемент которого строка с вопросом, так же я храню кол-во тем. Сейчас для примера будет 1 тема, но это не важно. Важно то, что при попытке сделать это получаю каскад ошибок, и вопрос: что я делаю не так и как это сделать лучше?
Код:

```
#ifndef QPACK1_H
#define QPACK1_H

int theme_amount = 1;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > questions(theme_amount + 1, std::vector<std::string>(6, " "));


questions[1][0] = "Вы попали на тему: Name of the theme\n" ;    // сначала номер темы, потом номер вопроса(по 5), 0 вопрос - название темы.

questions[1][1] = "Question 1";
questions[1][2] = "Question 2";
questions[1][3] = "Question 3";
questions[1][4] = "Question 4";
questions[1][5] = "Question 5";


#endif
```

Список ошибок:

```
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(8,1): error C2466: невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(8,17): error C2087: questions: отсутствует индекс
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(8,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(10,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(10,1): error C2040: questions: "int [1][1]" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>"
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(11,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(11,1): error C2040: questions: "int [1][2]" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>"
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(12,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(12,1): error C2040: questions: "int [1][3]" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>"
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(13,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(13,1): error C2040: questions: "int [1][4]" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>"
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(14,19): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\qpack1.h(14,1): error C2040: questions: "int [1][5]" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>"
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\CHGK_game.cpp(44,52): error C2088: [: недопустимо для class
1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\CHGK_game.cpp(46,48): error C2088: [: недопустимо для class
```

Основной код программы:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "qpack1.h" //список вопросов



struct players
{
    std::vector<std::string> name;
    std::vector<int> score;
};




int main()
{   
    int pl_amount, qst_number = 0;
    players plist;
    std::string input;
    
    std::cout << "Enter number of players(less then 10): ";
    std::cin >> pl_amount;
    
    plist.name.resize(pl_amount);
    plist.score.resize(pl_amount);
    plist.score.assign(plist.score.size(), 0);

    std::cout << "Enter players names: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < pl_amount; i++)
        std::cin >> plist.name[i];

    std::cout << "Tips: enter stop to left the game. \nUse + or - and number of player to give(take out) points to his score.\n";
    for (int theme_number = 1; theme_number <= theme_amount; theme_number++)
    {

        while (qst_number <= 4)
        {
            qst_number++;
            if (qst_number == 1)
                std::cout << questions[theme_number][0] << "\n";

            std::cout << questions[theme_number][qst_number] << "\n";

            TryAgain:
            getline(std::cin, input);

            if (input == "stop")
                goto Results;

            if(input.size() != 2 || !(input[1] > '0' && input[1] <= '9'))
            {
                std::cout << "Incorrect input.\n";
                goto TryAgain;
            }

            if(input[1] - '0' > pl_amount || input[1] - '0' <= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Incorrect input(Player was not found).\n";
                goto TryAgain;
            }

            if (input[0] == '+')
            {
                plist.score[input[1] - '0' - 1] += qst_number * 10;
                std::cout << plist.name[input[1] - '0' - 1] << " Gets + " << qst_number * 10 << " points!\n";
            }
            else
                if (input[0] == '-')
                {
                    plist.score[input[1] - '0' - 1] -= qst_number * 10;
                    std::cout << plist.name[input[1] - '0' - 1] << " Gets - " << qst_number * 10 << " points!\n";
                }
                else { std::cout << "Please start input with + or -.\n";goto TryAgain; }
                     


        }
        qst_number = 0;
    }

    Results:
    std::cout << "The final score is: \n";

    for (int j = 0; j < pl_amount; j++)
        std::cout << plist.name[j] << " : " << plist.score[j] << " points. \n";
}
```

И еще есть проблема: при первом выводе темы и вопроса, сразу же после этого выводится Incorrect input, хотя ничего не было введено. (проверял заккоментив эту часть: )

> questions[1][0] = "Вы попали на тему: Name of the theme\n" ;    //
> сначала номер темы, потом номер вопроса(по 5), 0 вопрос - название
> темы.
>
> ```
> questions[1][1] = "Question 1";
> questions[1][2] = "Question 2";
> questions[1][3] = "Question 3";
> questions[1][4] = "Question 4";
> questions[1][5] = "Question 5";
> ```

В общем, как фиксить?)

Comment: Это все надо делать внутри функций.

Comment: Блин(. А есть возможность все таки сделать это отдельно, что бы удобно хранить все вопросы?Просто в будущем планирую сделать много вопросов, по много пакетов(файлов), и просто в программе хранить, ну такое...

Comment: Если это данные, то храните их в текстовых файлах.

Comment: @DedalusMorffino `>> в подключаемом файле я создаю и инициализирую двумерный вектор` что-то мне подсказывает, что лучше так не делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле qpack1.h

```
extern const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > questions;
```

В файле qpack1.cpp:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > questions = {
   { "Вы попали на тему: Name of the theme\n",
     "Question 1",
     "Question 2"
     "Question 3"
     "Question 4"
   },
   { "Вы попали на тему: Name of the theme\n",
     "Question 1",
     "Question 2"
     "Question 3"
     "Question 4"
   },
}
```